# How can i capture clicks in RecycleView using databinding and MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

i have lots of adapters and views, viewsmodels and so on. Since its hard to maintain those i would like to use databinding and mvvm for that case. Now i tried to forward the item clicks into the viewmodel. Since its a recycleview i would lovely not loose the functionality to have less memory usage.

Currently i have a view (Activity) which sets the ViewModel. The ViewModel itself has an Adapter. The adapter has a Constructor which receives the viewModel and set this into the item.

The Item uses this to send the events back to the ViewModel. How does it affect the memory? Is there a better way doing this? I used RXJava before but this looks like the same concept, doesnt it? Here's my sample code (truncated).

**View**

```
public class ScenesFragment extends BaseFragment implements Observer {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.scenesFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.scenes_fragment, container, false);
    this.scenesListViewModel = new ScenesListViewModel(getContext());
    this.scenesFragmentBinding.setViewModel(this.scenesListViewModel);

    View view = this.scenesFragmentBinding.getRoot();
    return view;
}

}
```

**BaseLayout**

```
<layout ... >
    <data><variable name="viewModel" type=".viewmodel.ScenesListViewModel"/></data>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}"
            app:layoutManager="@{viewModel.layoutManager}" />
</layout>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ScenesListViewModel extends Observable implements IViewModel {

    public final SceneAdapter adapter;
    private List<Scene> scenes = new ArrayList<>();

    public ScenesListViewModel(@NonNull Context context) {
        this.adapter = new SceneAdapter(context, scenes, this);
     }

    public void onRemoveClick(Scene scene) {
        Timber.d("Clicked remove in the scene:" + scene);
    }
}
```

**Item Layout**

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="scene"type=".model.Scene"/>
        <variable name="viewModel" type=".viewmodel.ScenesListViewModel"/>
    </data>
               <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sceneDelete"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onRemoveClick(scene)}"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_white_48px"/>
                 </LinearLayout>
   </layout>
```

and finally the adapter which set the viewModel into the item.

**Adapter**

```
public class SceneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SceneAdapter.BindingHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Scene> scenes;
private ScenesListViewModel scenesListViewModel;

public SceneAdapter(Context context, List<Scene> list, ScenesListViewModel scenesListViewModel) {
    this.context = context;
    this.scenes = list;
    this.scenesListViewModel = scenesListViewModel;
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(SceneAdapter.BindingHolder holder, int position) {
    final Scene scene = scenes.get(position);
    holder.binding.setScene(scene);
    holder.binding.setViewModel(scenesListViewModel);
    holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

Another way doing it is to set a Listener in the ViewModel, but this is more likely mvp then mvvm. I could also use RXJava again and create a Subject within the adapter, but i would like to solve it with the android on-board tools.

Answer (score -1):

in your BindingHolder subclass implement onClickListener

```
class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements OnClickListener {
      // code code code
 }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code code code, use getAdapterPosition() to get the... adapter position
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this has nothing todo with databinding and its one of the possible ways which i wrote at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the same ViewModel in the ViewHolder by using "by activityViewModels".

Comment: It is from 2017.. and beside of that it's Java, not Kotlin.